# Why is Datastax Opscenter eating too much CPU?

Tags: cpu-usage, opscenter, cassandra-2.1

Environment :

```
machines : 2.1 xeon, 128 GB ram, 32 cpu
os : centos 7.2 15.11
cassandra version : 2.1.15
opscenter version : 5.2.5
3 keyspaces : Opscenter (3 tables), OpsCenter (10 tables), application`s  keyspace with (485 tables)
2 Datacenters, 1 for cassandra (5 machines )and another one DCOPS to store up opscenter data (1 machine).
```

Right now the agents on the nodes consume on average ~ 1300 cpu (out of 3200 available). The only transactioned data being ~ 1500 w/s on the application keyspace.

Any relation between number tables and opscenter? Is it behaving alike, eating a lot of CPU because agents are trying to write the data from too many metrics or is it some kind of a bug!?

Note, same behaviour on previous version of opscenter 5.2.4. For this reason i first tried to upg opscenter to newest version available.

From opscenter 5.2.5 release notes : 
"Fixed an issue with high CPU usage by agents on some cluster topologies. (OPSC-6045)"

Any help/opinion much appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you run https://github.com/patric-r/jvmtop or java flight recorder for a little bit during the runs? The number of metrics does depend on the number of tables but it could also be from GCs or some other services (ie backup/restore, repairs). Coul you try to upgrade to version 6.0.5? there have been a lot of improvements since 5.2.5.

Comment: Hi Chris, thank you for fast response.

Comment: About updating to 6.0.5 i am affraid i`m on cassandra 2.1.5 and if i remember correctly isn`t supported by. About the  backup/restore, repairs none on the flight, excepting maybe the read_repairs. Runing top found out that the agent pid is responsible for such high cpu demand.  Doing jps, getting the agents` pid and running "jstat -gcutil pid 1000 100" reveals alot of GC activity on the eden(i have G1GC with 12 Gb heap). I will try to check also with that tool you provided and i will try to come with more details and some picture taken from it runing

Comment: uploaded a print screen from jvmtop : http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=67858497675930199607 . The agent has same behaviour if i run it under root aswell. I`m running out of ideas... Updated so far opscenter, java, run under different user the agents, droped the keyspace, etc.

Comment: jvmtop is listing PIDs for you to choose, ie `jvmtop 9019` not just `jvmtop`

Comment: Hi Chris , ran it with agent`s PID : http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=77218272978659960277

Answer (score 0):

Observing with the awesome tool you provided Chris, on specific agent`s PID noticed that the heap utilisation was constant above 90% and that triggered a lot of GC activity with huge GC pauses of almost 1 sec. In this period of time i suspect the pooling threads had to wait and block my cpu alot. Anyway i am not a specialist in this area.

I took the decision to enlarge the heap for the agent from default 128 to a nicer value of 512 and i saw that all the GC pressure went off and now any thread allocation is doing nicely.

Overall the cpu utilization dropped from values of 40-50% down to 1-2% for the opscenter agent. And i can live with 1-2% since i know for sure that the CPU is consumed by the jmx-metrics.

So my advice is to  edit the file:

```
datastax-agent-env.sh
```

and alter the default 128 value of Xmx

```
-Xmx512M
```

save the file, restart the agent, and monitor for a while.

http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=71546243887469218237

Thank you again Chris.

Hope this will help other folks.